# apache rewrite subdomain php

Tags: php, apache

I currently have the following setup for my site:

www.mysite.com points to the static website at /var/www/sites/mysite/www
manager.mysite.com points to the php framework at /var/www/sites/mysite/admin/siteroot

The above was achieved using the ServerName and DocumentRoot commands in the apache config file.

What I need help with is getting
www.mysite.com/saas
to access the php framework at /var/www/sites/mysite/admin/siteroot just like the url was
manager.mysite.com/saas

If it makes a difference, the framework entry script is located at
/var/www/sites/mysite/admin/siteroot/index.php

There is also a .htaccess file in the /var/www/sites/mysite/admin/siteroot folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I hope this is not too confusing.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In you apache config for the `www.mysite.com` virtual host, add:

```
Alias /saas /var/www/sites/mysite/admin/siteroot
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives me a 404 error with the message "The requested URL /var/www/sites/mysite/admin/siteroot/index.php was not found on this server."  My apache logs show the error "File does not exist: /var/www/sites/mysite/www/var".  Something weird is going on.

Comment: @Littlebob Are there rules in the `admin/siteroot` directory (or in the mysite.com vhost) that may affect the routing? Does it work if you go straight to: `http://www.mysite.com/saas/index.php`?

Comment: Added the .htaccess rules above. I get the exact same error as mentioned previously when I go to http://www.mysite.com/saas/index.php